# unwanted indention level after C# attribute in Vim

Tags: c#, vim

Vim is indenting method definitions an extra level after an attribute. This is driving me crazy but I can't figure out how to make it stop. I've disabled indenting entirely but this isn't behavior I want. Is there a way to make Vim not indent an extra level after an attribute definition?

Here is a sample:

```
[Foo]
  public void Bar()
  {
  }
```

Comment: your not the only one with this problem - http://bit.ly/GRP5020

Comment: The link you posted isn't working for me. I'm trying to sift through the manual on indent. Perhaps there is something in here that will help me fix this. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grab [from here](https://github.com/vim-scripts/sharp-Indent) cs.vim file and put it in your `vimfiles\indent` folder.

Notice that you should have a string `filetype indent plugin on` in your vimrc file.

Comment: That is absolutely beautiful! Works great!

Comment: Very useful, even after all this time. Plus one!